# Bitbucket pipeline uploading unwanted files to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a repo with the following files:

```
app.js
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
package-lock.json
package.json
```

I want to zip `node_modules/ app.js package.json`and upload them to S3. I wrote the pipeline below:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches: # Pipelines should that will be triggered when a push is made in the below branch
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to S3
          script:
            - zip -r archive.zip node_modules/ app.js package.json
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.5.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 
                COMMAND: 'upload-only'
                ZIP_FILE: 'archive.zip'
                S3_BUCKET: 'lambda-bucket/lambda'
                LOCAL_PATH: '$(pwd)'
                ACL: 'private'
```

The pipelines runs successfully, but it uploads all the files in the repo (including the newly created zip) to S3. How can i ensure the pipeline only uploads the zip file?

Comment: try changing the `LOCAL_PATH` to be `$(pwd)/archive.zip`

Comment: i made the change and got the following error /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/archive.zip directory doesn't exist.

Comment: ah, ok - then maybe you can create the zip in an empty folder and use the path to that folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-aws-with-s3/

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches: # Pipelines should that will be triggered when a push is made in the below branch
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to S3
          script:
            - mkdir artifact
            - zip -r artifact/archive.zip node_modules/ app.js package.json
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.5.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 
                COMMAND: 'upload-only'
                S3_BUCKET: 'lambda-bucket/lambda'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'artifact'
                ACL: 'private'
```

This creates a new folder (`mkdir artifact`),  builds the zip in that folder (`zip -r artifact/archive.zip ...`) and uploads the folder `LOCAL_PATH: 'artifact'`